# Likelihood function for a hyperplane

Tags: probability, distributions, likelihood

I have a hyperplane defined by $y = b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3$.

I have a list of $n$ data points $(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)_i, i=1\ldots n$.

These data points have been measured with errors drawn from a normal distribution known variances $(\sigma^2_y, \sigma^2_{x_1}, \sigma^2_{x_2}, \sigma^2_{x_3})_i$. Each set of data points has a different set of known variances.

I want to calculate the likelihood of a set of coefficients $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$, i.e., the probability of the data given those coefficients. What is the appropriate likelihood function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The tricky part is that there are many implicit parameters.**  This becomes clear when the problem is carefully formulated, so **let's distinguish the reality from the data.**

Conventionally, we use Greek letters for the (unknown) reality, so express the hyperplane as the set of points

$$\mathcal H(\beta) = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,y)\mid y - \beta_1 x_1 - \beta_2 x_2 - \beta_3 x_3= 0\}.$$

Your model supposes the probability density of an observation $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y)$ being made at some point with *unknown* coordinates $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\eta)$ is proportional to

$$f(x_1,\ldots,y; \xi_1,\ldots,\eta; \sigma_{x_1},\ldots,\sigma_y) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma_{x_1}\cdots\sigma_y}\exp\left(-\frac{(x_1-\xi_1)^2}{2\sigma_{x_1}^2} - \cdots --\frac{(y-\eta)^2}{2\sigma_{y}^2}\right).$$

Substituting $\beta_1\xi_1+\beta_2\xi_2+\beta_3\xi_3$ for $\eta$ expresses this as a function of the $x_i,$ $y,$ the $\xi_i,$ the $\sigma_{*},$ and the $\beta_i.$  The $x_i$ and $y$ are the data; the $\sigma_{*}$ are known values (it might therefore be notationally better to use Latin letters and call them $s_{x_1}$ *etc*); and the rest--the $\xi_i$ and $\beta_i$--are the *parameters.* Assuming your $n$ measurements are independent, the likelihood will be the product of these probability density values.  Since the data and the $\sigma_{*}$ are known, the likelihood will be a function of $3n$ $\xi_i$ values and the three $\beta$ values: $3(n+1)$ parameters *in toto.*

---

For any given $\beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3),$ however, the likelihood will be maximized by projecting each $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y)$ orthogonally onto $\mathcal{H}(\beta)$ *with respect to the Euclidean metric* determined by the corresponding $\sigma_{*},$ thereby estimating all the $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)$ values conditional on $\beta.$  Consequently, the problem of maximizing the likelihood reduces to a three-dimensional optimization.

The orthogonal projection of $(x_1,\ldots,y)$ onto $\mathcal{H}(\beta)$ with respect to the $(\sigma_{x_1}, \ldots, \sigma_y)$ metric is

$$(\xi_1,\ldots,\eta) = (x_1,\ldots,y) - \frac{\beta_1x_1 + \cdots + \beta_3x_3 - y}{\sigma_{x_1}\beta_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_{x_3}\beta_3^2 + \sigma_y}(\sigma_{x_1}\beta_1,\ldots,\sigma_{x_3}\beta_3,-\sigma_y).$$

Upon substituting the right hand side for the left hand variables in the likelihood you will obtain an explicit formula for it in terms of $\beta$ (given the data and the $\sigma_{*}$).